# Drawing an off-axis parabolic mirror in pst-optexp and pst-optic

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

Having looked through the pst-optexp manual, it doesn't seem that there is a built-in off-axis parabolic mirror. I'm trying to make a diagram of a lab setup that goes like this:

1. Collimated beam falls on a converging lens.
2. The focal point of the lens is at the same point as the focal point of the OAP.
3. OAP reflects a collimated beam at a 90 degree angle to the incident beam.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX. Can you tell us more about this thing since we are not all optics people. Best is to draw on a paper or on Paint and upload the picture to the question by editing it.

Comment: Have you tried using my solution? If you're having problems with it, I would be glad to here about it in order to get some feedback about this feature before integrating it in the main release :)

Comment: @Christoph - Geez, I totally missed all of the replies to this post. I'll try implementing your solution over the weekend. 
percusse - An off-axis parabolic mirror is a mirror whose reflective surface is in the shape of a piece of a parabolic surface instead of a piece of a spherical surface. These are nice because they don't exhibit spherical abberations.

Comment: is there a bug related to `\oapmirror`? I've been trying to draw one in my experimental setup sketch without success. In fact, I tried to compile the code from Christoph and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Version 5.1 of [`pst-optexp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-optexp) contains an off-axis parabolic mirror as `\oapmirror`. You must specify three nodes to align the mirror properly: the input nodes, the center node, where the actual mirror center is placed, and the focal point.

Here is an example for a mirror which reflects by 90°:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,4)
  \pnodes(5,0.5){In}(1,0.5){C}(1,2){Focus}(1,4){Out}
  \addtopsstyle{Beam}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!40!white}
  \begin{optexp}
    \oapmirror(In)(C)(Focus)
    \lens[n=1.53](Focus)(Out)
    \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.5](In){-}(Out)
    \drawbeam[ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsidePos=0.2, arrowscale=3, arrowinset=0.3, linestyle=none](In){1}
  \end{optexp}
  \psdot(Focus)\uput[0](Focus){focus}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The other parameters for an OAP that would make sense would be the reflected focal length and the angle at which the reflected beam exits. From what I understand, that angle is 90 degrees in most cases (like what your solution shows here), but they are definitely also made with different exit angles. Here's a link to the specific model I'm using in my lab. On the right side of the page you can download the datasheets (one is a PDF) and look at all of the parameters: http://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=MPD254254-90-F01